# Is there a way to wrap a list of comma separated values from a cell in quotation marks?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a cell formula I can use to produce the following with some SUBSTITUTE functions?

I've got data in a cell like:

`sun, sky, cloud, clouds`

and I'm trying to wrap each value in quotation marks to give me

`"sun", "sky", "cloud", "clouds"`

I'm struggling as there are multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is enough - plz let me know if there is a case I haven't thought of:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"(\w+)","""$1""")
```

[image]

So [Regexreplace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en-GB) works in a similar way to Substitute, but lets you specify what is to be replaced using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

In this example:

- \w means any letter
- + means repeat one or more times so \w+ represents a word.
- ( ) means a capture group. Whatever is in the brackets will be captured and can be retrieved later.
- $1 means retrieve the contents of the first (and only) capture group
- "" stands for a single " (double-quote).

[Rexegg.com](https://www.rexegg.com/) is a useful reference.

You could modify this to include sun-screen and cloud's if you wanted to:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"([\w'-]+)","""$1""")
```

Comment: Very good way to do this. Could you add a small explanation? 

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
=CHAR(34)&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",CHAR(34)&", "&CHAR(34))&CHAR(34)
```

with your data in cell A1.  That will only work if you have spaces after each comma in the original data.

Comment: Does `CHAR(34)` represent `"`? Where do I get the full list?

Comment: @Madhurjya yes it does. you can see the list by running this formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(CHAR(ROW(A1:A1000)))`

Comment: Here's a sheet with all of them.  There are more that are higher than the highest here, but they're all asian characters i think.  You just add the numbers in column A to the numbers in row 1 to know the character code. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1byvtYNaKNpCMxarEyrU8KzD6RqP3TY_ZdMpeOPYhIkM/edit?usp=sharing